# Ubuntu 18.04 in USB not booting. Secboot : error during falcon reset -110

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb, 18.04

I bought a new laptop, Lenovo Legion Y530 CPU, Intel i7 8750H, 32GB RAM, Nvidia 1050 Ti. I tried to run ubuntu from a bootable USB and I get this error:

```
ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS 
ACPI Error: 3 table load failures,10 successful 
... 
nouveau: secboot:error during falcon reset: -110
nouveau: gr: init failed, -110
```

I have seem a few posts here similar to this question, but they are all about people who had already ubuntu installed, and a problem of drivers. But what can I do if I can not even boot ubuntu from USB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. disable secure boot(delete the platform key)
2. press <kbd>**e**</kbd> after you boot (in the grub menu) and add `nomodeset`parameter in the line which starts with linux (just type nomodeset at the end of that line)
3. install linux, and do the same step 2 while booting up linux from your PC and install proprietary nvidia drivers

Comment: Hey! everything worked, thanks! But when I went to boot again after step 3 it didnt, it got blocked loading files and blocks (Mounting the partition? ) But it boots if I load kernel 4.15.0-20 instead of 4.15.0-29. Although, I don't think this is related with the problem of my question.